# jqm or js - alternative line to populate an option menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to nail down a problem in a big app made in jquerymobile.

In certain situations, the option menu is not populated.

```
opcja = $("<option />");
opcja.appendTo($("#" + whichmenu)).text(element);
```

Before I cut off all the irrelevant parts, which will probably take me a few days, I would like to know:

**Is there an alternative way to the presented above - a line of code which could replace the above one (with appendto) and do the same, either in javascript or in jqm?**

Maybe the alternative will happen to work in all the cases.

Comment: how about `console.log($("#" + whichmenu))` before to see if your select if found?

Comment: are you using `data-native-menu="false"`?

Comment: whichmenu works fine, number of elements is also properly identified, also in those cases in which the subroutine does not work.  

As for native menu - I did not know about it, but I will definitely use it because with it the select option looks way better. This will require a separate question, though, because I can't make this change to happen.

Comment: Following information on the net, I added
     $(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
  $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = false;
 });
before $(document).ready(function ()...  and modified option
     <option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="top"  data-native-menu="false" 

It is not the right way, is it? There is no change in the look of the option menu.

Comment: Now all selectmenus are converted into popup or dialog, so you need to use `.selectmenu("refresh")` after adding new options. Modifying option button won't work this way, you need to dig inside DOM for the generated popup/dialog.